# Technique/methodology name for html page within page?

Tags: html, jsf

Is there a specific name for when you have a contained html page within a container html, where the contained page gets its contents replaced without affecting the container (à la ajax)?

FYO, What I want to do is have a site navigation menu in the container, and replace the contents of the contained page depending on the user's actions. I'm using JSF.

Comment: Like an iframe? or ajax?

Comment: @Dementic it seems an iframe could be an alternative for me, thanks.